# Recombine Number to Equal Math Formula

Tags: algorithm, number-theory

I've been thinking about a math/algorithm problem and would appreciate your input on how to solve it!

If I have a number (e.g. 479), I would like to recombine its **digits** or combination of them to a math formula that matches the original number. **All** digits should be used in their **original order**, but may be combined to **numbers** (hence, 479 allows for 4, 7, 9, 47, 79) but each digit may only be used **once**, so you can not have something like 4x47x9 as now the number 4 was used twice.

Now an example just to demonstrate on how I think of it. The example is mathematically incorrect because I couldn't come up with a good example that actually works, but it demonstrates input and expected output.

Example Input: `29485235`

Example Output: `2x9+48/523^5`

As I said, my example does *not* add up (2x9+48/523^5 doesn't result in 29485235) but I wondered if there is an algorithm that would actually allow me to find such a formula consisting of the source number's digits in their original order which would upon calculation yield the original number.

On the type of math used, I'd say parenthesis () and Add/Sub/Mul/Div/Pow/Sqrt.

Any ideas on how to do this? My thought was on simply brute forcing it by chopping the number apart by random and doing calculations hoping for a matching result. There's gotta be a better way though?

**Edit**: If it's any easier in non-original order, or you have an idea to solve this while ignoring some of the 'conditions' described above, it would still help tremendously to understand how to go about solving such a problem.

Comment: Wonder how the question can have 2 answers and 0 views. Bug?

Comment: With regard to your edit, I recommend you start with the "Countdown numbers game" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countdown_%28game_show%29#Numbers_round. It's designed to be solved by humans in 30 seconds, so it removes a lot of the difficulty that is in your problem (by accident, I assume).

Answer (score 4):

For numbers up to about 6 digits or so, I'd say brute-force it according to the following scheme:

1) Split your initial value into a list (array, whatever, according to language) of numbers. Initially, these are the digits.

2) For each pair of numbers, combine them together using one of the operators. If the result is the target number, then return success (and print out all the operations performed on your way out). Otherwise if it's an integer, recurse on the new, smaller list consisting of the number you just calculated, and the numbers you didn't use. Or you might want to allow non-integer intermediate results, which will make the search space somewhat bigger. The binary operations are:

- Add
- subtract
- multiply
- divide
- power
- concatenate (which may only be used on numbers which are either original digits, or have been produced by concatenation).

3) Allowing square root bloats the search space to infinity, since it's a unary operator. So you will need a way to limit the number of times it can be applied, and I'm not sure what that will be (loss of precision as the answer approaches 1, maybe?). This is another reason to allow only integer intermediate values.

4) Exponentiation will rapidly cause overflows. 2^(9^(4^8)) is far too large to store all the digits directly [although in base 2 it's pretty obvious what they are ;-)]. So you'll either have to accept that you might miss solutions with large intermediate values, or else you'll have to write a bunch of code to do your arithmetic in terms of factors. These obviously don't interact very well with addition, so you might have to do some estimation. For example, just by looking at the magnitude of the number of factors we see that 2^(9^(4^8)) is nowhere near (2^35), so there's no need to calculate (2^(9^(4^8)) + 5) / (2^35). It can't possibly be 29485235, even if it were an integer (which it certainly isn't - another way to rule out this particular example). I think handling these numbers is harder than the rest of the problem put together, so perhaps you should limit yourself  to single-digit powers to begin with, and perhaps to results which fit in a 64bit integer, depending what language you are using.

5) I forgot to exclude the trivial solution for any input, of just concatenating all the digits. That's pretty easy to handle, though, just maintain a parameter through the recursion which tells you whether you have performed any non-concatenation operations on the route to your current sub-problem. If you haven't, then ignore the false match.

My estimate of 6 digits is based on the fact that it's fairly easy to write a [Countdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countdown_%28game_show%29#Numbers_round) solver that runs in a fraction of a second even when there's no solution. This problem is different in that the digits have to be used in order, but there are more operations (Countdown does not permit exponentiation, square root, or concatenation, or non-integer intermediate results). Overall I think this problem is comparable, provided you resolve the square root and overflow issues. If you can solve one case in a fraction of a second, then you can brute force your way through a million candidates in reasonable time (assuming you don't mind leaving your PC on).

By 10 digits, brute force appears impossible, because you have to consider 10 billion cases, each with a significant amount of recursion required. So I guess you'll hit the limit of brute force somewhere between the two.

Note also that my simple algorithm at the top still has a lot of redundancy - it doesn't stop you doing (4,7,9,1) -> (47,9,1) -> (47,91), and then later also doing (4,7,9,1) -> (4,7,91) -> (47,91). So unless you work out where those duplicates are going to occur and avoid them, you'll attempt (47,91) twice. Obviously that's not much work when there's only 2 numbers in the list, but when there are 7 numbers in the list, you probably do not want to e.g. add 4 of them together in 6 different ways and then solve the resulting 4-number problem 6 times. Cleverness here is not required for the Countdown game, but for all I know in this problem it might make the difference between brute-forcing 8 digits, and brute-forcing 9 digits, which is quite significant.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers like that, as I recall, are exceedingly rare, if extant. Some numbers can be expressed by their component digits in a *different* order, such as, say, 25 (5²).

Also, trying to brute-force solutions is hopeless, at best, given that the number of permutations increase extremely rapidly as the numbers grow in digits.

EDIT: Partial solution.

A partial solution solving some cases would be to factorize the number into its prime factors. If its prime factors are all the same, and the exponent and factor are both present in the digits of the number (such as is the case with 25) you have a specific solution.

Most numbers that *do* fall into these kinds of patterns will do so either with multiplication or pow() as their major driving force; addition simply doesn't increase it enough.

Comment: Any idea how to do this in a different order?  I appended the question that the conditions are not set in stone, I'd very much appreciate ideas on how to solve such a problem while ignoring some of the conditions mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

Short of building a neural network that replicates Carol Voorderman I can't see anything short of brute force working - humans are quite smart at seeing patterns in problems such as this but encoding such insight is really tough.